# AWS Timestream queries over different measurements

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-timestream

Due to the way data is structured in Timestream, in which each row contains a different measurement, for example, load, speed, fuel (taking the sample IOT database) it becomes not obvious how to query data for questions that take more than one measurement in mind.

Is it possible to query for items that share a value column?
For example: For a given truck_id and time range, find out all records
where the speed is higher than 40 and the load is less than 100?

[IOT Sample database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSMbm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with tricky SQL, and a bit of abuse of aggregate functions, and GROUP BYs to generate the output you wish.

Otherwise, TimeStream doesn't support formatting data like you traditionally would on a relational database.